# Sending data in Constructor or using a function in another Activity

Tags: android, constructor

In IOS we call over **ViewController**(`Activity in Android`)  and can set it attributes like

```
 AnyViewController *view = [[AnyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"layoutFile];

 [view setName:@"AnyName"];

[self presentViewController:view ... blah blah]// new View is created and we have set its data using setName where Name is an attribute in AnyViewController class.
```

Now my question is how can we set this while creating an intent

```
Intent inten = new Intent(PresentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
```

is there any way like before or After calling this NextActivity.class.setName("anyName"); or passing some data in constructor as we pass context while calling AsyncTask

```
new AsyncTask(PresentActivity.this).exectue();
```

**Edit...**

I know all methods to send data between Activities.

1. Serializable
2. Intent.putExtra("keyName",type)
3. Parcelable
4. creating a static variable and get it in any other Activity(it is against OOP)

I want to know is there any method of sending data in constructor or calling any public method as i said  .. I may be wrong i want to know is there any  kind of method like given  to set an Attribute or sending data in Constructor...

`NextActivity(context).class` or `NextActivity.class.setName();`

**Is this possible if not Why is it?**

Answer (score 0):

You could pass some datas to the other activity like that :

```
inten.putExtra('name of your data', yourdata);
```

If you got some datas, use a Bundle :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putXXX('name of your data', yourdata);

inten.putExtras(bundle);
```

In your another activity, use :

```
getIntent().getExtras().getXXX('name of your data');
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to pass value using intent methods (putExtra,getStringExtra) like:

```
        Intent i = new Intent (PresentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("setName", AnyName);
        startActivity(i);
```

well, now in NextActivty class onCreate method you able to receive it:

```
        String anyName;
        Intent i = getIntent();
        AnyName = i.getStringExtra("setName");
```